# (Symfony2 + nginx) splitting traffic between upstream based on request directory

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, load-balancing

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this and haven't found anything that can help me for my specific situation. I am new to nginx so I am still getting used to things.

I have a Symfony application running across two web servers with `php-fpm` installed. The master server has the `nginx` and `php-fpm` whereas the second server just has `php-fpm`. I want all routes to `/admin/*` to be routed via the `main_server` upstream and everything else that is not `/admin/*` to go to the `default_balancer` upstream.

I have tried various things to no avail. I want all routes to still be handled by `app.php` (except for static assets) I just want the upstream server to change based on whether the request url is `/admin/*` or not.

Main server URL examples (will always go to `main_server` and will preferably throw error if `main_server` is not available instead of defaulting to other servers):

- /app.php/admin
- /app.php/admin
- /app.php/admin/
- /app.php/admin/login
- /app.php/admin/user/delete

Default Balancer URL examples (will always go to `default_balancer`):

- /app.php/
- /app.php/contact-us
- /app.php/store

*FYI: The above urls are typed in without the `/app.php` part into the browser but are handled internally this way because of the `try_files` section*

Here is my nginx conf file (excluded the unimportant bits).

```
upstream default_balancer {
    server 192.168.1.1:9000 weight=5; # main server
    server 192.168.1.2:9000 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s; # second server
}

upstream main_server {
    server 192.168.1.1:9000; # main server
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.local;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.local;
    root /var/www/vhosts/symfony/web;

    [...]

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass default_balancer;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }
}
```

Extra info: *reason I am doing this is because our designers handle uploading images via the admin panel on the website. Because assets are handled by the main server (that has nginx installed and serves the static assets) I figured it would be easiest just to forward all `/admin/*` routes to that single server. I am open to other solutions if they work.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL examples do not match your configuration. Assuming that you simply want URIs that begin with `/admin` to be sent to `/app.php`, you could add this block:

```
location ^~ /admin {
    fastcgi_pass main_server;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/app.php;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

If you also have static files under `/admin`, you may need a slightly more complicated:

```
location ^~ /admin {
    try_files $uri @admin;
}
location @admin {
    fastcgi_pass main_server;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/app.php;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying this. For some reason it always uses the `^/app\.php(/|$)` location and never hits the `^/app\.php/admin` location. I tested this by placing the server I don't want to hit into maintenance mode and then refreshing the admin URL and I get the maintenance page every now and then. Switching the rules around makes it so I only hit the one server. So I know that based on this it is only hitting the one rule no matter which one is placed first.

Comment: You are a godsend. This worked. Even gave a 502 when I brought the main server down and still had the other one up. Exactly what I wanted. And 10/10 for the static-files handling from `/admin`